# Foreign Key is not getting updated in Hibernate onetomany

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have seen many answers to this question but for some reason non of them work for me. I am new to hibernate mapping so not sure where I am going wrong. When I run the below code I get this exception.

```
Releasing statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@1033fef8: insert into user (email, firstname, lastname, PASSWORD, SALT) values ('myemail', 'myfirstname', 'mylastname', '$2a$10$dxzyxqhPFrrj.H3mROcZBOhhdm986gCra/5sHmCN5Y8CdJ8TUY1hu', null)]

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`contact_manager`.`user_roles`, CONSTRAINT `email` FOREIGN KEY (`email`) REFERENCES `user` (`email`))
Releasing statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@598fc658: insert into user_roles (role, email) values ('ADMIN_ROLE', 8)]
```

I don't know where 8 comes from for email value but with every run it gets incremented.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="userid", unique = true, nullable=false)
   private Integer id;

   @Column(name="email", unique = true)
   private String email;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
   private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>();

//getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer userRoleId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    //getters and setters
}

public User saveUser(User user) {
    Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    UserRole role = new UserRole();
    role.setRole("ADMIN_ROLE");
    role.setUser(user);
    userRoles.add(role);

    user.setUserRole(userRoles);

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);

    return user;        
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be mapping on the primary keys not arbitrary fields.

Comment: It doesn't have to be primary key, it can be done on any unique column?

Comment: hibernate assumes that the relation is mapped based on the primary keys, hence it tries to insert the primary key value (8) of the user into the specified column (email). Also why make the mapping an entity? Just use `@JoinTable`? An entity is only  necessary if there are more values then the 2 keys.

Answer (score 0):

The Model mapping and the the saveUser method are a bit unorthodox.
Please change the model to the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_model")
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Auto)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name="email", unique = true)
   private String email;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
   private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>();
}

@Entity
public class UserRole{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Auto)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

When saveing something ensure to not create the same user role more than once. So if you wana give an user the same role read it from the database first. This should also be the standard workflow. You probably will create valid user roles before creating an user or update it afterwards. So the cascade makes no sense on the userRole relation.The fetch Eager for a @ManyToOne annotation has no effect, because this is the default value. I would advice you to not use JoinColumn in that way. JPA is an OBJECT relational mapping framework so the data model should be object based and not be bound to the relational data model.
Other changes

- Removed the @Table annotation. If you plan to use a custom nameing take a look at the nameing strategies. The exception is the user object because user is often a reserved word in databases.
- Changed the id to long. I see no reason for Integer as key.
- Hibernate does probably know it better which strategy to use when you are a beginner